# How to generate a list of ranges to subset rows from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to generate **a list of ranges** based on lists to subset rows from a dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_index = [10,20,30]
end_index = [15,25,35]

range_list = [10:15, 20:25, 30:35]

# assume df is a dataframe with 50 rows
df = df.loc[np.r_range_list,:]
```

How to generate the range_list from start_index and end_index? Any suggestions is welcome!

Comment: `df.loc[np.r_[10:15, 20:25, 30:35]]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `zip` with `list` for list of tuples:

```
range_list = list(zip(start_index, end_index))
print (range_list)
[(10, 15), (20, 25), (30, 35)]
```

And then use list comprehension for filter:

```
dfs = [df.loc[s:e] for s, e in range_list]
```

If want one big DataFrame add [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfbig = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Al together, convert `zip` object to list is not necessary:

```
dfbig = pd.concat([df.loc[s:e] for s, e in zip(start_index, end_index)])
```

Comment: It works with zip! Thank you, jezrael, for your comprehensive answer.